# Central vertex of a cyclic graph and of a complete graph

Tags: graph-theory

What is the central vertex for a cyclic graph $C_n$? and for complete  graph $K_n$?

The eccentricity is the same for all vertices!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$C_n$ and $K_n$ don’t have single central vertices. The [*centre*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_center) of a graph is the *set* of central vertices, i.e., the set of vertices whose eccentricities are equal to the radius of the graph. The centres of $C_n$ and $K_n$ are their entire vertex sets.